# Stripe annual billing but different set of months

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to bit a customer on an annual basis but the billing should happen between August current year - July of the next year. Can this be done via webhooks or some other method on Stripe ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [update the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription) with the [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription-trial_end) parameter to choose the next billing date (and [`prorate`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_subscription-prorate) set to `false`).

When the "trial" ends, a new billing cycle will start and Stripe will attempt to bill the customer for the plan's amount.

More info about this: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/billing-cycle#api